# Angular css transition not working completely

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css

I tried to make a transition in nav bar. Its partially working. I don't know why it happen.

```
<style>
nav {
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
  height: 100px;
}

.ng-hide {
  height: 0;
}

p {
margin-top:100px;
}

</style>

<body ng-app="myApp">    
<nav class="container-fluid navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-hide="myCheck">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <a href=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<p>Hide the NAV: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCheck"><p>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
</script>
</body>
```

Include the bootstrap css, angular and angular-animated libraries.

Comment: Did you check *what* `ng-hide` does? *The way* it does what it does is the reason why it's not going to work with transition. You can't do it like you are doing but you really want to use ngAnimate if you want transitions.

Comment: after when i using ng-animate also, transition not working. Actually ng-hide  does display as none. Right?

Comment: Yes. But you are not using ngAnimate properly. In order to implement animation for ngHide/ngShow you need to write specific CSS rules. Check documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide